# How can I push a python script onto my android device?

Tags: android, python, sl4a

I am trying to figure out how to push a script I wrote in python to my android device.  I am not using an emulator I am using an actual device.  I thought I might be able to do it using adb to push it but I can't seem to figure it out.  Also I have SL4A and py4a on the device.

**EDIT:** I solved the problem by turning on developer settings on my device.

Comment: `adb push` it. `adb push` it real good.

Comment: I tried to push it using adb but it didnt pick up the device.

Comment: Well I would fix that problem. Start by searching the internet for info on how to get adb working *with your particular phone*. On Windows, I had to install drivers to get adb to talk to my Galaxy Nexus.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a python app and then send yourself the code over e-mail and copy paste it into the python app or save it somewhere it should run on your android.

Comment: Or maybe I misinterpreted what you meant. Whatever :P

Comment: I would do that but I feel like that would be a hassle to do everytime I want to run a python app on my device.

Comment: Yeah I guess, but I did it and it only takes about a minute if you already have the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following tools:

1. Android monitor: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monitor.html I love this one as its integrated to my android studio.
2. DDMS: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html This is more used with Eclipse.

However both of these tools can be installed independently.